# Seleccionar celdas que tienen ciertas palabras

Tags: r, rstudio, r-dplyr

Tengo un data frame similar a este

```
dt=data.frame(datos=c("pizza simple","pizza con jamon","pizza con queso","hamburguesa con queso",
                      "nachos con queso","papas","tacos","chalupa"))
```

y tengo un vector con palabras clave

```
claves=c("pizza","queso")
```

Deseo ver cuales celdas tienen esas palabras, algo así:

```
                  datos  
1          pizza simple   pizza
2       pizza con jamon   pizza
3       pizza con queso   pizza queso
4 hamburguesa con queso   queso
5      nachos con queso   queso
6                 papas
7                 tacos
8               chalupa
```

He intentado con este código

```
dt %>% filter(str_detect(datos,claves))
```

Sin embargo lo que obtengo no es lo que busco

```
                  datos
1          pizza simple
2       pizza con queso
3 hamburguesa con queso
```

Answer (score 1):

Tu solución es adecuada salvo por un pequeño detalle, el segundo parámetro de `str_detect` espera un patrón de expresiones regulares y le estas pasando simplemente un vector de cadenas. El patrón adecuado a usar sería un `or` que se expresa como `pizza|queso`, por lo que la solución podría ser:

```
dt %>% 
   filter(str_detect(datos, paste0(claves, collapse="|")))

                  datos
1          pizza simple
2       pizza con jamon
3       pizza con queso
4 hamburguesa con queso
5      nachos con queso
```